# Are these dialogues in `Anjaana Anjaani` are tribute to `Sangam`

Tags: reference, anjaana-anjaani, sangam

In the movie *Anjaana Anjaani* there is a scene in a bar where Akash and Kiara are fooling around and start playing some kind of game where Kiara is trying to help Akash learn how to woo girls.

There is the following dialoge, where they call each other by the names Gopal and Radha.

> We've got news.. the enemy has advanced. Their men are moving forward. They've captured most of our men. We don't have much time But what will happen if they find you, Gopal?
>
> There's nothing I can do. Radha, I will have to stay back. For my people. Till the end.
>
> You will have to leave.
>
> But what about us? All those dreams, those promises?
>
> Tell me.
>
> We have just this night.
>
> This night.
>
> This moment.
>
> You're good.
>
> Okay.
>
> I am starting to get to know you a little too well....and I am not liking it.
>
> Why?

So is this a reference to the movie *Sangam* where the lead characters have the same names Radha and Gopal?

I want to know if the directors or producers used these names Gopal and Radha because they're from *Sangam* or is it just random?

Note: Akash is played by Ranbir Kapoor who is the grandson of Rajkapoor who directed the movie *Sangam* and also acted in the same movie, however not as Gopal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the directors used these dialogues as a tribute to 'Sangam' as this is not the first time Ranbir has paid tribute to his family members. He has done the same in his movie 'Rockstar' and many award shows as well.